# Add section (add_settings_section) to a custom page (add_submenu_page) not working

Tags: plugins, theme-development, theme-options

I am adding a section to sub menu page but nothings is outputting except an empty form with three hidden fields.

```
   <?php

function testTheme_add_admin_page() {
//add admin page
    add_menu_page('testTheme custom options', 'Test Theme', 'manage_options', 'alecaddd_testTheme', 'testTheme_create_page', get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/sunset-icon.png', 110);

//add submenu pages
    add_submenu_page('alecaddd_testTheme', 'General Settings', 'General', 
'manage_options', 'alecaddd_testTheme', 'testTheme_create_page');

//activate custom settings
    add_action('admin-init', 'testTheme_custom_settings');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'testTheme_add_admin_page');
function testTheme_custom_settings() {
    register_setting('testTheme-settings-group', 'first_name');
    add_settings_section('testTheme-sidebar-options', 'Sidebar Options', 
'testTheme_sidebar_options', 'alecaddd_testTheme');
}

function testTheme_sidebar_options() {
    echo "Sidebar Settings";
}

function testTheme_create_page() {

    require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/templates/testTheme-
admin.php';
}

function testTheme_general_settings() {
//Add submenu page
}

function testTheme_settings_page() {

}
```

testTheme-admin.php code

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <?php settings_fields('cleanblog-settings-group'); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections('alecaddd_cleanblog'); ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

`add_action('admin-init', 'testTheme_custom_settings');`.
Action specified here is wrong.

Update it to:
`add_action('admin_init', 'testTheme_custom_settings');`

And it should work.

Comment: thanks man.Now its working. Was unable to figure out that....

Comment: @ali Can you mark it as answer.

Comment: @Ali Since it's working for you, you should mark it as answered, it keeps the queue cleared and helps us with the points too. Thanks